# Language (%s and %d), using array with no error

Tags: php, arrays, explode, printf

I would like to ask if any of you know how to develop a function in PHP that will let me use a language file when echoing out content from a database. I want to be able to change the language, so that if I want to change what the user will see, it will be changed forever.

However: What I would like to do is to store an array in a database table. Then I would like to echo that information out using vsprintf. The only problem I have now is that if I for instance would like to change the language file and add a %s or %d, I would get an error when printing out the result.

Basically, I would like this to work:

```
<?php
echo vsprintf("%s sent you %d coins at %s", array("John", 128));
?>
```

I would like for the code above me to output:

```
John sent you 128 coins at %s
```

When echoed out.

However, I'm getting an error because I have too many %s's in my code. I though about making myself a function that allowed for this by exploding the %s's and %d's and then leave them when the array was looped through. But then I need to explode it by two seperate characters.. someone have an idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
  echo vsprintf("%s sent you %d coins at %s", array("John", 128, '%s'));
?>
```

Comment: I would like for the function to automatically write %s and %d where that is when I change the variable in PHP without having to update every record (a couple thousand) in the database each time..